# Proving a derived MAC is secure via reduction

Tags: provable-security, mac

I don't have a very specific question, but reductions have been a weaker suit of mine and I was wondering if there is a secure MAC scheme, and a derived MAC' that uses MAC but modifies it in some way, how could you prove that MAC' is secure via reduction? I know how to do reductions for PRGs and PRFs, but not sure how to use it for MACs. I don't have a concrete example, but a walkthrough of the general process would be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example would be the following: Suppose you have a secure MAC scheme $M=(K,T,V)$ with the keygen, tagging and verification algorithms. Then define the new scheme $M'=(K,T',V')$ with $T'(k,m)=T(k,m)\|s$ for some constant string $s$ and $V'$ checking with a reject for the presence of $s$ before returning whatever $V$ would have returned on the shortened input.

The security reduction for $M'$ would then usually go as follows: You're given an adversary $\mathcal A$ against the sEUF-CMA security of $M'$ and need to construct $\mathcal R$ running the sEUF-CMA experiment to break $M$ using $\mathcal A$ as a sub-routine.
For any MAC'ing query from $\mathcal A$ you would then forward and on the way backwards, you'd add $s$ at the end of the tag.
For any Verifying query from $\mathcal A$ you then check if $s$ is present at the end of the tag and if not, immediately respond with the reject and otherwise forward the stripped tag-message pair also forwarding the result.
In the end, if $\mathcal A$ wins, it needs to have sent you a valid verify query which passed forwarded verification which also means the reduction adversary $\mathcal R$ has won.

Comment: @kelalaka I have renamed $\mathcal A'$ to $\mathcal R$ to avoid this confusion.

Comment: Well, I was rather on that adversary of $M$ should be $\mathcal A$  and adversary of $M'$ $\mathcal A'$, the reverse was conflicting my mind ( maybe just me) and have to read more than once :). You can delete this, too.